# Wordpress Downloads Appending .HTML

Tags: wordpress, caching, digital-downloads

I’m not sure why, but on my latest Wordpress post, where I have some media files linked with the “download” attribute, when they are downloaded they append .html to the file name. (i.e. file name.pdf.html).

I am using siteground and Cloudflare caching, and my initial instinct is that this is the root cause. Older posts and media do work fine.

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: This question needs more details so that someone can actually help you.  You should consider reading [ask] and  [mre]

Answer (score 0):

try `https` download links

`https://file name.pdf`

**I had the same problem, my download links were http and were not followed when clicked. I replaced them with ssl links and the problem was solved**

Comment: Thanks, but they are https links already.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason deleting and re-uploading the same files made it work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).